# How to get Path of Common Project for Media Upload from Multiple Project in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hy I want to upload a picture or video from Admin Panel Project and then access it from Website Project.

I want to upload it on common project folder but unable to get the access of common project.
How can I add media on common project Gallery folder and then use that for front end website.

[image]

Comment: string ParentFolder = Directory.GetDirectories("Infodice.NYP.Web.Common/Gallery/ImageGallery");
                    uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.ImageFile.FileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(ParentFolder, uniqueFileName);
                    model.ImageFile.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                    ImageGallery imageGallery = new ImageGallery

Answer (score 0):

Bit hacky but use `IHostingEnvironment` to get the webroot and replace the path with your common project folder.

```
var webRoot = env.WebRootPath;
var commonPath = webRoot.Replace("Infodice.NYP.Web.Admin\\wwwroot", "Infodice.NYP.Web.Common\\Gallery\\ImageGallery");
```